# WSoD on CartThrob Settings Screens

Tags: cartthrob, white-screen-of-death

I just updated a site from EE 2.5.1 to 2.6.1, and from CartThrob 2.1.3 to 2.3.2. When I try to access any CartThrob settings pages, I get a white screen of death. The CartThrob Order Manager works fine. Here's what I've tried, with no luck:

- I enabled debugging on my `admin.php` file. No new errors.
- I enabled debugging in `system/index.php`. No new errors.
- My PHP error log is blank
- My PHP memory limit is *really* high (750M on my local server)
- I disabled extensions

Suggestions?

Comment: Did you try enabling error reporting in the /system/index.php file?

Comment: @JimWyse Good suggestion! Just tried it, but the white screen remains!

Comment: Are errors turned on in the php.ini? Can you put up a simple php file with <?php { echo "12345 ?> and see if an error comes back?

Comment: When you upgraded, did you overwrite the folders, or delete them and upload the new files fresh? Try that and see what happens.

Comment: I'm pretty sure error logging is turned on in php.ini. I have `error_reporting = E_ALL`, `error_log = "C:\wamp\logs\php_errors.log"`, `log_errors = On`, and `display_errors = On`. I created the broken PHP file you suggested, and I got a front-end php error, and a php error in the *Apache* error log, but nothing in the PHP error log.

Comment: @JimWyse I deleted the old folders and uploaded the fresh ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue myself. I uninstalled the HealthCheck accessory and viola - CT Settings! If you are using HealthCheck, you will have problems with CartThrob.